# Why formdata submitted to server not changed after I being set by `formdata.set()`?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am encrypting password for users:

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="usernamePasswordLogin(event);">
```

```js
// want to encrypt password field before submit formdata
    function usernamePasswordLogin(x) {
        var formData = new FormData(x.target);
        var formDataEntries = formData.entries()
        var formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next()
        var pair;
        while (!formDataEntry.done) {
            pair = formDataEntry.value;
            if (pair[0] === 'password') {
                var encrypt = new JSEncrypt()
                encrypt.setKey(publicKey)
                var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(pair[1])
                formData.set(pair[0], encrypted)
                console.log('formdata', formData.get(pair[0])) // print encrypted password
                break;
            }
            formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next();
        }
    }
```

When I submit the form, the console log shows formdata has been changed:

> formdata YWFHmy9Da5x7XSKnF0jhgIrJbJF/eWo193VJIsYqcGbRh5gLVyL6U+ZGxiphOYSXVgXMQ0041c+IaLRvguwBXiwYm5pKE7xCFamdiwAzRA0YCzdIN9Rh/0rKq6G/QAAEbetdlgeDGnS8+hYo8eDJKZWhroNqku8vTxVT8+YiAcM=

but at server side, I see original plain text password.

Comment: FormData has nothing to do with normal form submission. [Description From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) *The FormData interface provides a way to construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can be sent using the fetch() or XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can *initialize* a `FormData` object from a `<form>`, there is no ongoing link between them. Edits to the data in a FormData object are not reflected back in the original form.

Use DOM to set the `value` of the `<input>` if you want to update the form before it is submitted.

---

Note that it is almost never useful to encrypt a password with `JSEncrypt` or similar on the client.

Most usecases are better handled by sending the password over HTTPS and hashing it server side.

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the submit and change the form data being transmitted to server without changing the form input DOM's value? browser's remembered password might messed up if I change password for user